# What may cause Ubuntu to not be able to shut down and limp in the logout screen?

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

I know, that this question seems to be too general, but I would appreciate any ideas, which could help me start diagnosis of the problem.

My problem is that sometimes (about 50% of the time) I am unable to shut down the system properly.

I click Shut Down..., the desktop dissapears and a purple screen with Ubuntu logo appears. The same screen that appears when I turn on the system. Only difference is that there is no indication of any action. The dots under the logo, that usually blink in sequence are all still and after no action for a few minutes, I turn on the computer manually.

The computer shows no visible problems, it is a new machine and boots perfectly each time. I am just concerned, that this is not the right way to do things.

Please could you hint me some possible causes?

EDIT:

Recently I got a "Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 experienced an internal error" message. The executable is:

```
usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/colord/colord
```

And the cause is a segmentation fault.

So maybe I should just report the problem and wait it out, right?

Comment: It may be your video driver.  I had a similar symptom with my ATI card in 11.10 using the standard proprietary driver, but it worked OK with the standard open-source driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there is some active program that is not terminating during the Shutdown process.

Comment: Thank you! is this possible even when the desktop screen disappeared? Aren't by then all the user programs supposed to be shut down?

Comment: lets see if this true or not... boot ur ubuntu and shutdown without open any program... then boot ubuntu, close all program before shutting down. is there any difference between two of this...

Comment: Open a set of usually used programs and shut them down -> not able to shut down properly. Boot and shut down without any programs -> shut down properly. Boot and shutdown starting and closing each program from the above mentioned set above one at a time -> shut down properly.

Comment: so looks like you have to close all program before shut it down :)

Comment: Did you try `sudo halt` in the command line, or `sudo shutdown -h now`?  This was a reported bug with the GUI shutdown thing, it sometimes doesnt shut down.